# Using VBA Macro To open Link to picture

Tags: image, excel, hyperlink, vba

My goal of this program is to open a picture in a folder by selecting a cells value in the active row which im using the line to do.

```
picture = Cells(ActiveRow, 6).Value
```

I am getting a Run time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error

Here is my full code

```
Sub Picture_Click()

   Sheets("Master").Unprotect Password:="Conti1"
   Sheets("Records").Unprotect Password:="Conti1"

   Dim picture As String
   Dim ActiveRow As Long


   Worksheets("Master").Activate

        ActiveRow = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        picture = Cells(ActiveRow, 6).Value

ChDir"P:\926_TM\03_LocalExchange\Tracking_and_Labeling\LabEquipment\pictures"

    Workbooks.Open picture

End Sub
```

I am trying to use the value from the selected cell to be the name of the picture file in the selected folder, the picture I would like to open.

also I am getting a value of -1 for ActiveRow

Any help would be great!

Comment: The `Workbooks.Open` method is for opening Workbooks, not pictures.

Comment: Would it be 'applications.open' then ?

Comment: Technically it is `Application.Workbooks.Open`, but you don't need the Application qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open a picture with the `Workbooks.Open` method, as that method is exclusively for opening workbooks.

One option is to use a `Shell` command to open the picture.  In this example, I will open a picture located on the the Pictures folder named `Test.png`

```
Private Sub OpenPic()
        Shell "mspaint.exe C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\Test.png"
End Sub
```

This will open the picture in paint.

Adapting this method to your code:

```
Sub Picture_Click()

   Sheets("Master").Unprotect Password:="Conti1"
   Sheets("Records").Unprotect Password:="Conti1"

   Dim picture As String
   Dim ActiveRow As Long


   Worksheets("Master").Activate

   ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
   picture = Cells(ActiveRow, 6).Value

   Shell "mspaint.exe P:\926_TM\03_LocalExchange\Tracking_and_Labeling\LabEquipment\pictures\" & picture

End Sub
```

This assumes that the value in `Activerow, 6` includes the file extension.

As an aside: I would add that you don't need to define ActiveRow at all and could just use it as-is.

So this:

```
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
picture = Cells(ActiveRow, 6).Value
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
picture = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value
```

And you can omit the ActiveRow variable altogether.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRow is a Long, so you cannot select a row and say that is a number. You would simply write

```
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

In the immediate window, if you write ?Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select, it will return a Boolean Value, not a number.

Also to open a file you should use the FollowHyperlink method:

from msdn:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://example.microsoft.com"
```

Your link would replace the one in the example of course.

```
picture = "P:\926_TM\03_LocalExchange\Tracking_and_Labeling\LabEquipment\pictures\" & Cells(ActiveRow, 6).Value
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=picture
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will help you to **open in default photo viewer**.
I tried,

```
Sub image_opener()
    Dim photo_path As String
    photo_path = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Selection.Address).Value
    PID = Shell(photo_path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

but the above code didn't work for me. I think the McAfee in my PC is preventing the excel from running that shell command.

So, I created a openImg.bat file containing

```
%1
```

%1 basically takes the input from the user.
Normally we can open image using this openImg.bat by,

```
openImg.bat path_of_image/image.jpg
```

So, I edited the VBA accordingly

```
Sub image_opener()
    Dim photo_path As String
    photo_path = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Selection.Address).Value
    PID = Shell("bat_file_path\openImg.bat " & photo_path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

photo_path = "image_path/image.jpg" . Finally I setup a shortcut key for the macro from **Developer>Macros>Options>Shortcut Key** .
The above worked for me.